# how to get the Uid inside a child and another push ID child

Tags: android

[this the structure of my firebase database and as you can see there is Uid inside the random ID under comments chile. can someone help me how to get that Uid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epj1O.png)

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epj1O.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I really don't understand your question try to explain it in detail.

DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Comments");

You can get references of your comments by above line and addValueEventListener to it. By doing this you will get all the data available in your comments. After that, you just have to filter your data if you need a particular UUID.